# ImageView is small after rotation of device

Tags: android, gridview, rotation, imageview, android-viewholder

After rotation of device -> Image (`id=list_image2`) remains small like it was at portrate mode
 Seems it is because I change count of Columns gridView.setNumColumns(3);, but viewholder still contains previous imageview with previous width and height, also I tryed to make gridView.invalidate(); in onConfigurationChanged...but no result

added to activity in Manifest

```
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Here is item_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/list_row_root"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="1dip"
        android:paddingRight="1dip"


 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/list_image2"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:minWidth="@dimen/grid_item_width"
     android:minHeight="@dimen/grid_item_height"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_action_cloud"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"

        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/list_image2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/list_image2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/likes_RelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/field_likes"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/list_image2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/list_image2"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/likes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="265465" />

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/btn_favoutites"
             android:layout_width="25dp"
             android:layout_height="25dp"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/likes"
             android:src="@drawable/btn_rating_star_on_normal_holo_dark"
             android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_RelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/likes_RelativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/likes_RelativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/likes_RelativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/likes_RelativeLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/field_like_clickable_style" >

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my adapter:

```
publ

ic class LazyAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter{
    public LazyAdapter2(Context context, ArrayList<WallImage> d) {

            mContext = context;
            data=d;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)// default
                .build();
        }

 public View getView( int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         final ViewHolderItem viewHolder;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
             convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid, null);
             viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
             viewHolder.thumb_image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image2); // thumb image
             convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }


        WallImage imageObject = data.get(position);
        viewHolder.likes.setText(imageObject.views);
        imageLoader.displayImage(imageObject.preview, viewHolder.thumb_image, options);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a sidenote, I know it's not an answer (that's why it's a comment): `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` is a bad habit -- try to adapt to the orientation rather than avoid to consider it.

Comment: imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY); change it to .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED). It will helpful when image size is smaller.

Comment: @SidDhangot no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing of item_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_row_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="1dip"
    android:paddingRight="1dip"
     >
     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_item_height"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@android:color/transparent"
             />
```

after doing of ImageView  `android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_item_height"` => after rotation of screen image size remains constant, but to resize imege in ImageView I use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` after that image is slighly cutted , but problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

Not just invalidate but how about like this with *Handler.post()*?:

```
new Handler(getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        gridView.invalidate();
    }
});
```

Comment: where should i do it?

Comment: @Unuchek How about in the *onConfigurationChanged* if it is called after rotation?

Comment: @Unucheck Sorry, I don't have an idea any more.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is due to the use of `convertView` in your `getView` method?
It keeps the original layout and don't recreate it when orientation change.

You could add to your `ViewHolderItem class` a boolean member that indicates the screen orientation.

And when you recycle the view, you test your `viewHolder` orientation. If it's different from the current screen orientation, don't recycle it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)`
and

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageObject.preview, viewHolder.thumb_image, options);
viewHolder.thumb_image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FILL_XY);
```